# Is there a guide or publication listing U.S. / Canadian shuls that are handicapped-friendly?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, publications, handicap-disabled-impair

My apologies to any reader that I may inadvertently offend by use of the term "handicap". I am uncertain of another good term to convey my message...

Parsha Kedoshim, which addresses not to insult the deaf or place a stumbling block before the blind, motivated me to inquire regarding synagogues that are friendly to handicapped people. Has someone published a list of U.S. / Canadian synagogues that cater to various handicaps? I am looking for this in terms of mainly weekly Shabbat and holiday services, not for social events.

Some examples:

- Synagogues that have a ["loop" system](http://www.hearingloop.org/) that assists people wearing hearing aids or cochlear implants
- ASL (American Sign Language) interpreters for all or part of the services
- Handicapped ramps to the shul bimah (2 places I know of are Boca Raton Syngogue, FL and Hebrew Institute of Riverdale, NY. Any others?)
- Wheelchair accessible synagogues, possibly with Shabbat elevators so that all parts of the synagogue are accessible
- Services for mentally-disabled congregants such as autism, slow learners, ADHD, etc.
- Siddurim written with Braille

These are some of the handicaps that I can think of, offhand. The guide / list, of course can include others.

Comment: I don't know, but you may try contacting Yachad, a division of the OU, or Our Way, a division of Yachad: either of them may have a list. (Both aim toward inclusion in the general Orthodox Jewish community: Yachad, outside of Our Way, is officially for those with disabilities but seems to focus mostly on mental disabilities, whereas Our Way is for the deaf and hard of hearing.)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. I have been a member of Our Way for many years, and know the main people there. AFAIK, Yachad hasn't published this guide, but B"N, I will check, again.

Comment: They should all be friendly

Comment: @hazoriz, no doubt most synagogue attendees are friendly to handicapped people. The question here is not whether the attendees are but whether the synagogues themselves (architecture etc.) and their programming (interpreters etc.) are. Perhaps the question can be clearer (though I thought it was clear enough).

Comment: @msh210 he is not the right word accommodating

Comment: @hazoriz My intent is not to say Lashon Harah. But, this is not a rumor. It is a visible fact, and a relatively well-known one. B"N, I'll include a link to an article that indicates this problem, at least for the deaf. And, yes, I got the distinction of what you mean by "friendly" vs. "accommodating". In my title, it is used similar to the term "user-friendly". That was my intent. No shul that I know of is hostile to the handicapped.

Comment: @DanF I do not think halachakli the magarity are obligated to use the public money to make there shul friendly for the minority (even if they are handicapped) unless they want to, (it might be an obligation to make it physically accessible for everyone, but it is accessible even if it is not wheelchair accessible, (there are other means of transportation then a wheelchair) )

Comment: Why do you need a loop system if it is not for social events

Comment: @hazoriz The loop system is currently being used in several shuls in the U.S. from what I gather. We have been exploring this in our shul, as well, but there MAY be a halachic problem with its use on Shabbat. AT any rate, it helps people with aids and implants hear the davening much better.

Comment: Any synagogue in the United States that had a major remodeling after 1990 would have to comply with the egress and accessibility requirements of the Americans with Disabilities Act.  This law is most strict in demanding compliance in new construction.  Existing structures do not have to be updated for minor remodeling, but they often do if there is significant modification to the building.  In some recently remodeled synagogues you will find ramps leading to the bima, accessible water fountains, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/disdirectory.htm) from the OU lists synagogues that are handicapped accessible.